# Relations domain,range,inverse,composition

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let X = {0, 1, 2}, Y = {a, b, c}, Z = {α, β, γ}. The relations A ⊂ X × Y and B ⊂ Z × Y are defined
as follows
A = {(0, b),(1, b),(1, c),(2, c)}, B = {(α, a),(β, b),(γ, a)}.
Find
dom(A−1), rng B and B−1 ◦ A

Is it some tricky question and I should pay attention to this because of this subsets ? Or just do it like always?

I did it like this:
dom(A-1)={b,c}, rngB={a,b}, B−1 ◦ A={(0,β),(1,β)}

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: First, $\;A\;$ is a subset of a cartesian product and thus I suppose $\;A-1\;$ , whatever that means, must be a subset of the same cartesian product...Does $\;A-1\;$ mean "the relation $\;A\;$ minus the identity relation"...orwhat?

Comment: Maybe $A^{-1}$...

Comment: A-1 I meant inverse of A. Also B-1 inverse of B. Sorry for not writing it correctly.